# Cocoapods installs pods not specified in projects Podfile

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

When I run pod install cocoapods installs several pods not listed in the current projects Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PodUser' do
 # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
 # use_frameworks!

 # Pods for PodUser

 pod "PodTest"

 end
```

My pod install output:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0)
Using FirebaseCore (3.6.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.10)
Using Google (3.1.0)
Using GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Using PodTest (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 8 total pods installed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CocoaPods installs the specified pods and all of those pods' dependencies.

If you look at PodTest.podspec and its dependencies and recursively follow the podspec's for those dependencies, it should match the pods that get installed.

See also the file Podfile.lock that gets created alongside the Podfile to see a list of the relevant pods and their dependencies.

Comment: This was such an odd case, I create a local test pod with the exact same name, but was not resolved correctly locallly and so fetched one from the internet, together with all it's dependencies. I also have started some Firebase stuff recently and thought something other than dependencies might be influencing this, maybe some global setting perhaps. I would have never guessed it was a PodTest actually has dependencies such as Google etc.